# How to solve pyobjc installation problem?

Tags: python, pyobjc

```
pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Quartz
  Using cached pyobjc-framework-Quartz-6.2.2.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Charan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qnwuu7s1\\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Charan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qnwuu7s1\\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Charan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-v7jcwbrn'
         cwd: C:\Users\Charan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qnwuu7s1\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Charan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qnwuu7s1\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\setup.py", line 64, in <module>
        Extension(
      File "C:\Users\Charan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qnwuu7s1\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\pyobjc_setup.py", line 420, in Extension
        if "clang" in get_config_var("CC"):
    TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You seem to be installing [pyobjc] on a Windows machine. See https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#unsupported-platforms: "*PyObjC provides interfaces for the system APIs on macOS and as such cannot support Linux and Windows.*". You need to clarify what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pyobjc modules are only for MAC OSX.  https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .  Looks like you are trying to install on windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

Pyobjc maybe install only for Macos.Window not include Framework, which available for macos.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34137595)